# Override Rails_Admin dropdown value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have two models: `Company` and `Salesperson` that look like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :salesperson
end

class Salesperson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end
```

In Rails_Admin, when I am trying to assign a salesperson to a company (Editing a Company), the sales person dropdown is showing values like:

```
Salesperson #1
Salesperson #2
Salesperson #3
```

Instead, I'm trying to get the name to display in the dropdown:

```
John Doe
Jane Smith
Bobby Jones
```

I've tried these solutions, but they didn't work.

[How to override value that appears in a dropdown in the rails_admin gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751845/how-to-override-value-that-appears-in-a-dropdown-in-the-rails-admin-gem)

[rails_admin Change belongs_to Drop-down to Display Options from Different Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590997/rails-admin-change-belongs-to-drop-down-to-display-options-from-different-field) (this is the exact problem I'm dealing with!)

Maybe it's because they're from older versions of Rails_Admin?  I'm on `0.8.1`?

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590997/rails-admin-change-belongs-to-drop-down-to-display-options-from-different-field) did end up solving my issue, however there was a catch:

In my case, I was wanting the salesperson's name to show up when I was editing the Company.  I wrongfully assumed that I needed to put the overrider method in the Company model.

Once I put it in the Salesperson model, all was well.